# Why failure to show error message Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

i have a strange issue showing a message in with my message service.
The service use this method for register the type of error:

```
if(msg.status>=400 && msg.status<500){
            return this.message.registerWarning(msg['error']['message'])
          }else if (msg.status>=500){
            this.message.registerError("Errore generico, contattare amministratore di sistema")
          }else{
            this.message.registerError(msg['error']['message'])
          }
```

Now, if i put the component at the top out of my div it show all [image]

```
<app-message *ngIf="msgpopp"></app-message>
 <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered">
    <div class="modal-content" *ngIf="idSSID && charge==false && !msgpass; else elseContent">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Cambio Password: {{idSSID}}</h5>
          <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" (click)="msgpopp=false; msgpop=true"></button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <label for="newPass" class="form-label">Inserisci Nuova Password</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input [type]="shopwd" class="form-control col-md-6" id="newPass" #newPass>
            <span class="input-group-text custom-shadow" id="basic-addon2" (click)="showpwd()"><i class="bi bi-eye"></i></span>
        </div>
        <label for="confirmPass" class="form-label">Conferma Password</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
            <input [type]="shopwd" class="form-control" id="confirmPass" #confirmPass>
            <span class="input-group-text custom-shadow" id="basic-addon2" (click)="showpwd()"><i class="bi bi-eye"></i></span>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The goal is to put it inside the popup. If i do this, all the message like "password not correct", "the password is need to be 8 character or more", etc are shown, but not the request error one.
[image: Example of different password]

```
<div class="modal-body">
        <app-message *ngIf="msgpopp"></app-message>
        <label for="newPass" class="form-label">Inserisci Nuova Password</label>
        <div class="input-group mb-3">
```

Comment: please share minimal reproducible code (more code) if possible a working stackblitz with the issue replicated!

Comment: Can you also include how you are creating the modal?